# Reflux trigger won't work without a delay in init

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux, refluxjs

I use Reflux, and normally I'm triggering after I made an ajax call, and it works well. For testing purposes I didn't need ajax call and I noticed that trigger won't work unless I give a min 5ms timeout. Here are working and not working example.

Not working example:

```
window.threadStore = Reflux.createStore
  init: ->
    @state = @getInitialState()
    @fetchThreads()
  getInitialState: ->
    loaded: false
    threads: []
  fetchThreads: ->
    # ajax call for not Testing, and just trigger for Testing
    @state.threads = FakeData.threads(20)
    @state.loaded = true
    @trigger(@state) # This will NOT work!
```

This will work:

```
window.threadStore = Reflux.createStore
  init: ->
    @state = @getInitialState()
    @fetchThreads()
  getInitialState: ->
    loaded: false
    threads: []
  fetchThreads: ->
    # ajax call for not Testing, and just trigger for Testing
    @state.threads = FakeData.threads(20)
    @state.loaded = true
    setTimeout( =>
      @trigger(@state) # This WILL work!
    , 500)
```

Can you explain why doesn't it work without a delay and should it? Is it a bug or something I don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the components get the empty array from `getInitialState` and it happens after the `trigger` was invoked.

`init` is called when the store instance is created which means the trigger in `fetchThreads` gets invoked immediately before a component was mounted. When the listening Component later gets mounted, it gets the empty array from the store on `getInitialState` instead.

I'd suggest the following change:

```coffeescript
window.threadStore = Reflux.createStore
  init: ->
    @state =
      loaded: false
      threads: []
    @fetchThreads()
  getInitialState: ->
    @state # TODO: State should be cloned for sake of concurrency
  fetchThreads: ->
    # NOTE: Assign a new state for the sake of concurrency
    @state = 
      loaded: true
      threads: FakeData.threads(20)
    @trigger(@state) # This will SHOULD work now ;-)
```